# Set onClickListener on view from included layout not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one layout which includes other layout inside. I tried to set onClikeListener on ImageView inside the included layout, but it's not working. But when I set background drawable it works. I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
//custom header
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sticky_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_header_close"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/big_cross_icon" />
</LinearLayout>

//activity_detail
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f1f2f6">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/custom_header"/>
</RelativeLayout>

//in Activity
View header = findViewById(R.id.header);
iv_header_close = (ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.iv_header_close);
iv_header_close.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.big_edit_icon));
iv_header_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish(); //not working
    }
});
```

I wonder why I can access to child view inside included layout but can't set OnClickListner. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Create your `iv_header_close` like this:

```
ImageView iv_header_close = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_header_close);
```

Instead of calling `finish()` Try to call `YourActivity.this.finish()`

What's happening is that, inside the `onClick` of your imageview, you don't have access to your activity so you have to access your activity using `YourActivity.this` if you want to access the methods of your activity.

Comment: No, it's not about finish but OnClickListener just doesn't work even I set toast or log.

Comment: It doesn't fix my prob.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is having the same issue five years later...
Using the `onClick` attribute on the view (ImageView, Button... mine was a button) inside the included layout file fixes the problem. However, note that the `onClick` attribute is now deprecated